# USAMO problem solution using APMO problem.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

prove that $[nx] \ge [x]+ \frac{[2x]}{2}+.....\frac{[nx]}{n} $

[.] is the floor function; $x\in R^+$

USAMO 1981.

So i posted this question earlier cause I couldn't find an 'understandable' solution anywhere, either they were wrong, or contained calculus or very bashy stuff.

I believe i have found a really nice solution using APMO 1999 / P2 (http://www.apmo-official.org/static/problems/apmo1999_prb.pdf).

So here goes,

NOTE THAT;

-[ia] + -[ja] $\ge$ -[ia+ja]

So we essentially need to prove

$-[nx] \le -[x]+ -\frac{[2x]}{2}+.....-\frac{[nx]}{n} $

Now using strong induction for all n $\le$ k, you know the drill, case for n=1,2 is trivial. assume it is true for all

n $\le k$

for some (k $\ge$ 2)

$-[x] \ge -[x]$

$-[x] + -\frac{[2x]}{2} \ge -[2x] $

.

.

.

$-[x]+ -\frac{[2x]}{2}+.....-\frac{[nx]}{n} \ge -[nx] $

adding all this stuff

-k[x] + -(k+1)$\frac{[2x]}{2}$ ....+ -$\frac{[nx]}{n}$ $\ge$ -[x] + -[2x] +..... -[kx]

Add -[x] + -[2x] +..... -[kx] to both sides and pairing [ia] and [ka-ia]on RHS

$(k+1)(-[x]+ -\frac{[2x]}{2}+.....-\frac{[nx]}{n})$ $\ge$ -[x]+ -[kx] + -[2x] + -[kx-x] +.... -[kx] + -[x]

$\ge -k[kx]$

After some very easy simplifying,

[(k+1)x] $\ge [x] + \frac{[2x]}{2} + ...... \frac{[(k+1)x]}{k+1}
$

I'll be honest, i could do this only as I had seen that APMO question but i believe this is a nice method which i couldn't find anywhere on google.

If there is any mistake, do let me know

Comment: Have you checked the solution using Abel's summation without induction? #19 at https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h424778p2403926

Comment: @NeatMath I am not familiar with Abel's summation

Comment: I didn't know either but just check out the solution and you'll understand. Just some re-arrangement and telescoping.

Comment: you can enclose all the mathematical expressions by $ (it makes readiing nicer)